# How to add jQuery validator method to check minimum number of select options selected or not

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the following optgroup type and want that minimum two options to be selected. So i want a validate method for this,

```
<select name="sector" id="sector" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="left">
<optgroup label="PQR">
<option value="ABC">abc</option>
<option value="DEF">def</option>
<option value="GHI">ghi</option>
<option value="MNO">mno</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: you can do something like this too http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nBLKu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add custom validation method like:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("check_options", function(value, element) {
return $(element).find('option:selected').length >= 2 ? true : false;
})
```

Then add rule "check_options" on your select.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when i integrated your code as folows:
$.validator.addMethod("sectorValidation", function(value, element) {
return $(element).find('option:selected').length >= 2 ? true : false;
}, 'Test');
but its not working .
I also integrated the error message, to it to display, but its not showing.